# Is there a way to switch UV checker on and off fast while working with UV editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

So as it said in the title, is there any way to turn on and off the checker fast, without going to the material editor and replacing the texture each time I am fixing or simply checking the UVs of the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Node Wrangler addon* to preview the checker texture

1. Enable *Node Wrangler* addon in *Preferences > Addons*
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Leftclick</kbd> to quickly preview the checker texture in the Shader editor
3. You can change the texture type in the UV editor

[image]

Comment: Ah.. Thank you. But how can I make it visible on 3D model? I can see it only on UV itself, but I'd like to see how the 3D object looks with it.

Comment: Hey :). Using the *Node Wrangler addon*, you can simply *Ctrl+Shift+Leftclick* to preview the checker texture.

Comment:  So there is no way to avoid adding a material editor on my small screen and creating an extra node in it?

Comment: Not that I know of :). Perhaps there's some addon exactly for this.

Comment: Not the worst problem, anyways. Maybe one day I'll write such an addon that shows checker on the model by clicking one button in UV editor, like in Maya. But need to learn programing first XD Thank you for your answer